# Unit Test View Model with Flow (Paging 3) doesn't return data

Tags: android, unit-testing, mvvm, android-viewmodel, android-paging-3

I would like to unit test my ViewModel that uses paging. When I do so, however, the returned data is not what I expect.

`MovieListViewModel`

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class MovieListViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val tmdbWebService: TMDBWebService,
    private val appDispatchers: AppDispatchers
    ) : ViewModel() {

    val items = Pager(
        config = PagingConfig(
            pageSize = 20,
        ),
        pagingSourceFactory = {
            MoviesPagingSource(tmdbWebService, appDispatchers)
        }
    ).flow.cachedIn(viewModelScope)

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch(appDispatchers.IO) {
        }
    }
}
```

`MoviesPagingSource`

```kotlin
class MoviesPagingSource(
    private val tmdbWebService: TMDBWebService,
    private val appDispatchers: AppDispatchers
): PagingSource<Int, MovieData>() {
    override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<Int, MovieData>): Int? {
        return state.anchorPosition?.let { anchorPosition ->
            state.closestPageToPosition(anchorPosition)?.prevKey?.plus(1)
                ?: state.closestPageToPosition(anchorPosition)?.nextKey?.minus(1)
        }
    }

    override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, MovieData> {
        return try {
            val page = params.key ?: 1
            val response = withContext(appDispatchers.IO) {
                tmdbWebService.getDiscoverMovies(page = page)
            }

            LoadResult.Page(
                data = response.results,
                prevKey = if (page == 1) null else page.minus(1),
                nextKey = if (response.results.isEmpty()) null else page.plus(1),
            )
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            LoadResult.Error(e)
        }
    }
}
```

`getDiscoverMovies` returns the following:

```kotlin
data class DiscoverMoviesResponse(
    @SerializedName("page") val page: Int,
    @SerializedName("results") val results: List<MovieData>,
    @SerializedName("total_pages") val total_pages: Int,
    @SerializedName("total_results") val total_results: Int,
)
```

This is my `MovieListViewModelTest` file:

```kotlin
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class MovieListViewModelTest {

    @get:Rule
    var mainCoroutineRule = MainCoroutineRule()

    private val tmdbWebService = mockk<TMDBWebService>(relaxed = true)

    private lateinit var viewModel: MovieListViewModel

    private val testDispatcher = AppDispatchers(
        IO = TestCoroutineDispatcher()
    )

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        viewModel = MovieListViewModel(tmdbWebService, testDispatcher)
    }

    @Test
    fun `Test fetching movie list`() = runBlockingTest {
        // Create mock movie data
        val mockMovieData = createDummyMovieDataResponse()

        // Mock API response
        coEvery { tmdbWebService.getDiscoverMovies(any()) } returns createDummyMovieDataResponse()

        // Collect the paging data flow and verify the items
        viewModel.items.collect { pagingData ->
            Assert.assertEquals(mockMovieData, pagingData)
        }
    }

    fun createDummyMovieDataResponse(): DiscoverMoviesResponse {
        return DiscoverMoviesResponse(
            page = 1,
            total_pages = 5,
            total_results = 40,
            results = createMockMovieDataList()
        )
    }

    private fun createMockMovieDataList(): List<MovieData> {
        // Create and return a list of mock movie data
        // Replace this with your actual mock data creation logic
        return listOf(
            createDummyMovieData(id = 1),
            createDummyMovieData(id = 2),
            createDummyMovieData(id = 3)
        )
    }

    fun createDummyMovieData(
        id: Int = 1,
        title: String = "Dummy Movie",
        overview: String = "This is a dummy movie overview",
        releaseDate: String = "2023-08-01",
        voteAverage: Double = 7.5
    ): MovieData {
        return MovieData(
            adult = false,
            backdropPath = "/dummy_backdrop_path.jpg",
            genreIds = listOf(1, 2, 3),
            id = id,
            originalLanguage = "en",
            originalTitle = title,
            overView = overview,
            popularity = 123.45,
            posterPath = "/dummy_poster_path.jpg",
            releaseDate = releaseDate,
            title = title,
            video = false,
            voteAverage = voteAverage,
            voteCount = 100
        )
    }
}
```

This is the `MainCoroutineRule` class

```kotlin
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class MainCoroutineRule : TestWatcher(),
    TestCoroutineScope by TestCoroutineScope() {

    override fun starting(description: Description) {
        super.starting(description)
        Dispatchers.setMain(
            this.coroutineContext[ContinuationInterceptor] as CoroutineDispatcher
        )
    }

    override fun finished(description: Description) {
        super.finished(description)
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
    }
}
```

The above `MainCoroutineRule` works fine for another ViewModel test.

The issue I have as mentioned is that the Expected and Actual Data do not match and in fact what is returned is not usable, but I'm not clear why. I'm not sure if my comparison is wrong or my mocking.

```
Expected :DiscoverMoviesResponse(page=1, results=[MovieData(adult=false, backdropPath=/dummy_backdrop_path.jpg, genreIds=[1, 2, 3], id=1, originalLanguage=en, originalTitle=Dummy Movie, overView=This is a dummy movie overview, popularity=123.45, posterPath=/du ...

Actual   :androidx.paging.PagingData@49d30c6f
```

Any help is appreciated.